# Use previous Zip output

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code to create a `IEnumerable<Tuple>` from 3 IEnumerables:

```
xs.Zip(xs.Transform()).Zip(xs.Transform().Transform())
```

On the second `Zip` can I access the result of previous `Zip` to avoid using:

```
xs.Transform().Transform()
```

Comment: `xs.Zip(xs.Transform()).Select(t => (t.Item1,t.Item2,t.Item2.Transform()))`. In general, the transformation for query syntax `let` is a `Select`, here, using `Zip` instead of `Select` for the first `Transform()` saves some code.

Answer (score 0):

> can I access the result of previous Zip to avoid using

Because `LINQ` processes the collections discretely and in steps it's hard to re-use things calculated in the same query.

Consider seperating and storing the results from your expressions into seperate variables.

Consider creating your own .Zip() extension that allows more than 2 collections. I wrote a sample one here for you:

```cs
IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<T, U, V, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> FirstCollection, IEnumerable<U> SecondColleciton, IEnumerable<V> ThirdCollection, Func<T, U, V, TResult> Expression)
{
    // get the amount of results that should be expected
    int expectedAmount = Math.Min(FirstCollection.Count(), SecondColleciton.Count());
    expectedAmount = Math.Min(ThirdCollection.Count(), expectedAmount);

    // create the result array
    TResult[] results = new TResult[expectedAmount];

    // carve out contiguous memory to place the results
    Span<TResult> resultSpan = results;

    // iterate through the collections using element at and run the expression on them, and set the value of the result span
    for (int i = 0; i < expectedAmount; i++)
    {
        // get the various items from the collections
        // we COULD use their raw enumerators for a speed boost but i don't want to write out the error handling and disposal
        T firstItem = FirstCollection.ElementAt(i);
        U secondItem = SecondColleciton.ElementAt(i);
        V thirdItem = ThirdCollection.ElementAt(i);

        // run the expression on them and set the value in the result
        resultSpan[i] = Expression(firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem);
    }

    // return the result
    return results;
}

string[] xs = { "A", "B", "C" };
int[] ys = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
string[] zs = { "Y", "M", "C", "A" };

IEnumerable<(string x, int y, string z)> zippedThreeItem = Zip(xs, ys, zs, (x, y, z) => (x, y, z));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", zippedThreeItem));

// outputs:
// (A, 1, Y), (B, 2, M), (C, 3, C)
```